# Why is an empty plot produced?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to plot the values of the functions `f[x]` and `der[x]`, but I am getting an empty plot. I am new to both Mathematica and simulation. Can anyone please help me.

```
Manipulate[
  fu[alfa], 
  {{alfa, 1, "α"}, 0, 1, 0.001, Appearance ->"Labeled"},
  Initialization :> (
    fu[alfa_] := 
      Module[{α, f, der},
        α = alfa;
        f[x_] = Exp[x];
        der[x_] = Sum[((t)^(k) x^(-α))/Gamma[k + 1 - α], {k, 0, ∞}];  
        Plot[{f[x],der[x]}, {x, 1, 1.5},
          AxesLabel -> 
            {Style["x", Italic],
             Row[{Style["f", Italic], "(", Style["x", Italic], ")"}]}, 
          ImageSize -> {300, 200}, 
          ImagePadding -> {{35, 20}, {20, 20}}, 
          PlotStyle -> Thick]])]
```

Comment: This code cannot be copied into a notebook in its current state because of syntax errors. For example, `[Alpha]` is not a valid symbol name.

Comment: what is the value of  `t` in `Sum[((t)^{k)...]`?

Comment: When ever you can't get a complicated piece of code to work, a good strategy is to start first with something that does work, a simple plot, then add one component to it, get it working, then add another and slowly build it back up until you add a piece that causes it to fail then focus your attention on getting that single piece to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few programming errors in your code. Probably the most deadly one is not taking into account that `der` depends on three parameters, `x, alfa` and `t`.

Here is a rewrite of your code that produced a plot that can be manipulated. Note, because the evaluation of `der` is time consuming, response to moving the sliders is rather sluggish.

```
Clear[f, der]
f[x_] := Exp[x]
der[x_, α_, t_] :=  Sum[t^(k) x^(-α)/Gamma[k + 1 - α], {k, 0, ∞}]

Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[x], der[x, alfa, t]}, {x, 1, 1.5},
    PlotRange -> {0, 5},
    PlotStyle -> Thick,
    AxesLabel ->
      {Style["x", Italic], 
       Row[{Style["f", Italic], "(", Style["x", Italic], ")"}]}, 
    ImageSize -> {300, 200},
    ImagePadding -> {{35, 20}, {20, 20}}],
  {{alfa, 1, "α"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{t, .2}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for your comments